# can anyone help me with this code im trying to create an instance for an ec2 machine using Golang and aws sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

can anyone help me with this code im trying to create an instance for an ec2  machine  using Golang and aws sdk  i keep getting an error

Couldn't create new instance: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
Process finished with the exit code 0
im really new to aws so any help or pointers tutorials or anything like this would be awesome.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/ec2"
)

func CreateInstance(client *ec2.EC2, imageId string, minCount int, maxCount int, instanceType string, keyName string) (*ec2.Reservation, error) {
    res, err := client.RunInstances(&ec2.RunInstancesInput{
        ImageId:      aws.String(imageId),
        MinCount:     aws.Int64(int64(minCount)),
        MaxCount:     aws.Int64(int64(maxCount)),
        InstanceType: aws.String(instanceType),
        KeyName:      aws.String(keyName),
    })

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return res, nil
}

func main() {
    sess, err := session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
        Profile: "default",
        Config: aws.Config{
            Region: aws.String("us-west-2"),
        },
    })

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to initialize new session: %v", err)
        return
    }

    ec2Client := ec2.New(sess)

    keyName := "ec2--teamspeak"
    instanceType := "t4g.nano"
    minCount := 1
    maxCount := 1
    imageId := "ami-0b0154d3d8011b0cd"
    newInstance, err := CreateInstance(ec2Client, imageId, minCount, maxCount, instanceType, keyName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Couldn't create new instance: %v", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("Created new instance: %v\n", newInstance.Instances)
}
```

i have tried many examples. I added environment setting using xset for windows to set variables .
but I'm really struggling. this is a hobbies but im really stuck here

Comment: Where and how do you intend to provide AWS credentials to your code?

Comment: I'm trying to follow this tutorial  https://www.learnaws.org/2021/10/16/aws-go-sdk-ec2-guide/#prerequisites

Answer (score 2):

It's due to the SDK cannot find the credentials for authenticating with AWS. The issue can be resolved by setting the aws environment variables.

See [Specifying Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/configuring-sdk.html) session

> set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY
> set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=YOUR_SECRET_KEY

The provider chain looks for credentials in the following order.

> - Environment variables.
> - Shared credentials file.
> - If your application uses an ECS task definition or RunTask API operation, IAM role for tasks.
> - If your application is running on an Amazon EC2 instance, IAM role for Amazon EC2.

*Or You can provide the credentials directly in the code*

**But in general, it is not recommended to hard-code credentials in your code**, instead use other credentials methods.

```
    sess, err := session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
        Profile: "default",
        Config: aws.Config{
            Region:      aws.String("us-west-2"),
            Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials("your-access-key", "your-secret-key", ""),
        },
    })
```

Comment: i tried it this way and i get the  AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
        status code: 401, request id: afa86

Comment: It is possible that you are using invalid credentials. Please make sure the credentials are correct and it have the necessary permissions as well.

Comment: what do i put in the last field where the session token should go

Comment: This value is optional. If you are using temporary credentials you will receive a "Session Token" with your "access-key" and "secret-key". When you request resources using temporary credentials, the call must include a session token.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html

Comment: thank you so much ;-) i worked it out from here but you put me on the right path . i hard code the creds but its ok its not production code just hobby code :-)

Comment: the problem was wrong machine type.